# Apply sum-of-squares to multiple numbers with reduce

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, lisp, elisp

I define square and sum-of-squares as:

```
(defun square(x)
  (* x x))
(defun sum-of-squares (x y)
  (+ (square x) (square y)))
```

then apply it an array with reduce:

```
(reduce 'sum-of-squares '(2 2 2))
```

but get result as 68 rather than 12.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reduction does

```
(sum-of-squares (sum-of-squares 2 2) 2)
```

which is

```
    (sum-of-squares 8 2)
```

which is 64 + 4

You can get the result you expect with

```
(reduce #'+ (mapcar #'square '(2 2 2)))
```

or

```
(reduce #'(lambda (x y) (+ x (square y))) '(2 2 2) :initial-value 0)
```

or by defining `sum-of-squares` to take an arbitrary number of arguments.

Comment: wow, thank you so much, any ideas to improve the sum-of-squares?

Answer (score 1):

I saw your comments:

> any ideas to improve the sum-of-squares?

```
(defun sum-of-squares (&rest lst)
  (let ((value 0))
    (dolist (element lst value)
      (setq value (+ (square element) value)))))

(sum-of-squares 2 2 2)
;; 12
```

It is faster than `reduce . mapcar`, because it won't generate intermediate data structure.